# Proof: Using properties of the integral

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

Not sure where to start; can someone give me a hint?

Problem:

If $ f $ is Riemann integrable and if  $ \lvert f(x) \rvert \le M $ on $[x,y]$ then $ \lvert \int^b_a f d\alpha \rvert \le M[\alpha(y)-\alpha(x)]$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$L(z) - L(b) = \int_b^z f\, dt$$

Comment: Thanks. how did you come up with this; why is it true?

Comment: It's because $$\int_x^b f\, dt + \int_b^z f\, dt = \int_x^z f\, dt.$$

Comment: Okay, I will think about how to use this. thanks!

Comment: Is the theorem I put in the question actually useful? I thought it would be but doesn't seem like it is:P

Comment: Yes, because if $f$ is bounded by $M$, then for $z,b\in [x,y]$, $$|L(z) - L(b)| = |\int_b^z f\, dt| \le M|z - b|$$